# Facebook Meta Tags for different browsers

Tags: facebook, meta-tags, jwplayer, html5-video

I am trying to post a video from a facebook application and I need it works for all browsers and for HTML5 if is available.

I'm using these 3 video formats for that: flv, mp4 and webm.

Here are the tags I'm using:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="My title" />
<meta property="og:description" content="My description" />
<meta property="og:type" content="video" />
<meta property="og:image" content="my_url_image.png" />
<meta property="og:url" content="my_url_video" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="my_app_id" />
<meta property="og:video:width" content="640" />
<meta property="og:video:height" content="480" />

<meta property="og:video" content="my_url_video.mp4" />
<meta property="og:video:type" content="video/mp4" />

<meta property="og:video" content="my_url_video.webm" />
<meta property="og:video:type" content="video/webm" />

<meta property="og:video" content="my_url_video.flv" />
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
```

Also, I have this script on the same php view in order to using jwplayer:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    jwplayer('container').setup({
        height: 480,
        width: 640,
        playlist:[{
            sources: [
                 { file: "my_url_video.webm" },
                 { file: "my_url_video.mp4" }, 
                 { file: "my_url_video.flv" } 
            ]
        }]
    });
</script>
```

The problem is when I post the video, only works flash in all browsers and I can't watch it on Mozilla with HTML5, or on a tablet or an ipad.

I don't know if the meta tags are ok or what could be the problem?.

Comment: I am pretty sure those meta tags only work in Flash. Regarding the player not working, do you have a link?

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering... but sorry, I can't post the link because it's an important project I'm working for... I took the Facebook example on this link: [link](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/) where says 'Attaching Audio and Video Data'.

Comment: Can you email it to us if  possible? http://www.longtailvideo.com/contact-us